# Show that two surfaces intersect orthogonally at a point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, orthogonality, tangent-line

Show that the two surfaces $z=7x^2−12x−5y^2$ and $xyz^2=2$ intersect orthogonally at the point (2,1,−1). [This means that their tangent planes at (2,1,−1) are orthogonal]

Comment: You should show some work that you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the partial derivatives for the first surface $z=f(x,y)$, you get 
$$
f_x=14x-12,\ \ f_y=-10y. 
$$
So $f_x(2,1)=16$, $f_y(2,1)=-10$, and the tangent plane is 
$$
16(x-2)-10(y-1)-(z+1)=0,
$$
with normal vector $$\tag1  v=(16,-10,-1).$$

For the second surface $z=g(x,y)$, since we need the point with $z<0$ we may write it as 
$$
z=-\sqrt{\frac2{xy}}.
$$
Then 
$$
g_x=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\,x^{-3/2}\,y^{-1/2},\ \ \ 
g_y=\frac1{\sqrt 2}\,x^{-1/2}\,y^{-3/2},
$$
so
$$
g_x(2,1)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,\frac1{2^{3/2}}=\frac14,\ \ \ g_y(2,1)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\,\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac12.
$$
So the second tangent plane is 
$$
\frac14\,(x-2)+\frac12\,(y-1)-(z+1)=0.
$$
The normal vector for the plane is then 
$$\tag2
w=(1/4,1/2,-1). 
$$
Now, looking at $(1)$ and $(2)$, 
$$
v\cdot w=\frac{16}4-\frac{10}2+1=0. 
$$
So $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal, and the two surfaces are orthogonal at $(2,1,-1)$.